# Ubuntu unstable login after upgrade to Radeon Vega 56

Tags: amd-graphics, 18.10, 19.04

I had an Nvidia 1060 in a Mac Pro 1.1 with Ubuntu 18.10. It worked pretty well, but I wanted an upgrade to something that would allow me to boot back into macOS.

I purchased an AMD Vega 56, which works well, but shortly after installing the card, the computer started to become pretty unstable after screen blank. After the screens go off, one of them (it's a dual-4K setup) will stay in a solid color, usually the Ubuntu purple, or it won't come back at all. It also started showing a weird color bar with grub on boot. I updated to 19.04 (fresh install), but that didn't help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is no official GUI to overclock your GPU.

But, https://github.com/BoukeHaarsma23/WattmanGTK seems to be what you're looking for. 
https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile is another alternative

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! I won't be able to try it until tomorrow--but I'll let you know what I find out!

Comment: Sorry about the delayed update--unfortunately, I haven't gotten it to install and run correctly. It keeps giving me an error when I run it. I read the note at the bottom of the page on errors running it, but I haven't been able to make enough sense of it to figure it out.

Comment: Did you tried to remove nvidia-drivers before install the vega ? amd product should work out of the box without using proprietary driver. However to get it work correctly I strongly advise you to use mainline kernel 4-15.0-47-generic a the moment. I've tried on fresh install with a radeon 7, working like a charm.

Comment: It had the same problem on a fresh install too... I ended up just getting a new computer. It works great in the new computer. I'm thinking it was just an issue with the Mac Pro and power or air flow.

Comment: Glad you solve it ! Not the cheapest way :p